# Postgres: Slow sub query

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, select

I have the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM person p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM task t
    WHERE t.person_id = p.id
)
LIMIT 100
```

The `task` table contains millions of entries. But somehow Postgres thinks it is smart to execute the inner select first. This results in the query to run for several minutes.

If I change the `SELECT 1` to `SELECT COUNT(1)`, I can trick Postgres into estimating that the inner select is more expensive. This results in the query being completed in less than a second.

How can I optimize the execution plan of Postgres without changing the above query?

Comment: LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing rarely makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an index on `task(person_id)`?

Without such an index, you might find that a `join` is a better choice for the query.

Comment: The index will most likely fix the performance. On the other hand the join may return a different result.

Comment: Even worse: the JOIN could be a terrible choice.

Comment: I do have an index on `task(person_id)`

Comment: @Nibor . . . Interesting.  I would expect Postgres to choose a better execution plan then.  Perhaps the statistics are not up-to-date.